# acmart with two \maketitle

Tags: acmart, titling

I'd like to create a paper and its supplement in one document (for easy referencing).  Below is an example. The problem is that the teaser figure and the abstract are saved before the \maketitle, and they are printed twice--once in each call. I'd like to reset them such that they won't be printed in the second time (supplement).

I tried the titling package, but it just stripped all the styles.

```
\documentclass[acmtog]{acmart}
%\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\acmJournal{CIE}\acmVolume{0}\acmNumber{0}\acmArticle{0}\acmYear{202x}\acmMonth{0}

\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}

\begin{abstract}
abstract
\end{abstract}

\begin{teaserfigure}
    \caption{Teaser figure to show once}
\end{teaserfigure}

\maketitle

\blindtext[5]

% second part
\setcounter{page}{1}
\title{Title---Supplement}

%\begin{abstract}
%\end{abstract}

\begin{teaserfigure}
\end{teaserfigure}

\maketitle

\blindtext[5]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second time, use the command `\maketitlesup` defined as `\maketitle` minus the abstract and the teaserfigure.

[image: a]

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass[acmtog]{acmart}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\acmJournal{CIE}\acmVolume{0}\acmNumber{0}\acmArticle{0}\acmYear{202x}\acmMonth{0}

%****************************************  added <<<<<<<<<<
\let\maketitlesup\maketitle
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\maketitlesup}{\@mkteasers}{}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\maketitlesup}{\@mkabstract}{}{}{}
%**********************************************************

\begin{document}
    \title{Title}
    \author{Author}
    
    \begin{abstract}
        abstract
    \end{abstract}
    
    \begin{teaserfigure}
        \caption{Teaser figure to show once}
    \end{teaserfigure}
    
    \maketitle
    
    \blindtext[5]
    
    % second part
    \setcounter{page}{1}
    \title{Title---Supplement}
    
    \maketitlesup % changed <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    
    \blindtext[5]
\end{document}
```

Used  `acmart.cls    2022/02/19 v1.83`